# JSONP Callback - data arrives unescaped when using jQuery call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

In my client html / JS code, I am calling an external API from within a domain to fetch json data. The other API runs in a separate domain, so basically it doesn't allow me to use regular ajax/xhr request. The solution we agreed upon with the API vendor was the they support jsonp.

So I am sending a jsonp request as follows:

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "https://rest.somevendor.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=204&deploy=1&cid=436&callback=myCallBack",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  type: 'GET',
  jsonp: "callback",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  processData: false,
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "NLAuth nlauth_account=xxxxxxx,nlauth_email=yyyyy@pppp-zzzz.com, nlauth_signature=FGrmr5fjd"
  },

  success: function(data){
    //console.log(data);
  }
});
```

My callback gets called with the json data, but there is a problem. 
When I make the same call from a browser REST client, I get back a valid json, which is escaped. However, when I make the same call from my client code, and I get back the data in my callback:

```
function myCallBack(data) {
  jsonString="";
  try{
    jsonString=JSON.parse(data);
  }catch(err) {
    alert(err.message)
  }
}
```

The parse function throws an exception resulting from character (") which are not escaped. For some reason, it seems that somehow the returned data gets unescaped prior to arriving to my callback function. Therefore, I cannot parse the data, and face a problem.

Comment: Why do you have `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`? It's a GET request. You don't have a request body to describe the content type of! Why do you have `processData: false,`? You don't have a `data` argument to prevent being processed!

Comment: What does the complete response look like?

Comment: Why do you have `headers: {
    "Authorization": "NLAuth nlauth_account=xxxxxxx,nlauth_email=yyyyy@pppp-zzzz.com, nlauth_signature=FGrmr5fjd"
  },`? You've using JSONP, you can't set custom HTTP headers.

Comment: Why are you hard coding a callback name in the URL? Why are you trying to override the (non-existent) dynamically generated callback name with `jsonp: "callback"`?

Comment: JSONP calls returns an object, it is not a string! jQuery does no parsing of it so what you are trying to do is not going to work.

Comment: Why are you expecting the service to return a JSONP response where the data is encoded as a string of JSON? That really isn't normal for JSONP.

Comment: Let me explain all concerns:
1. The processData is meaningless, I added it now just for testing if it changes anything
2. The content type is also meaningless, nothing changes if I comment it out
3. "Authorization" header is required for the API call to work. I can't omit i. But Authorization is not a custom header AFAIK, it is a standard header
4. The callback parameter tells the server which query param to look for to get the callback name. In this particular server, it is also meaningless, since they hard-coded the callback to which they call (regardless of what I pass to be "myCallBack"

Comment: Regarding the returning of an object rather than a string: I am not sure I understand, should I handle it differently? What is the correct way to implement such case? Assume jsonp is the only option now, because they cannot implement CORS support on server side from some reasons

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I bypassed this issue, by implementing a proxy server that makes the ajax call (without the CORS restrictions browsers enforce), and my client call is for this proxy.

Of course, in my proxy I implemented returning the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with the client domain, in order for this call to work.